# Implementing wss (Secure WebSocket) in Nodejs server

Tags: node.js, https, websocket

I am trying to implement a secure websocket through a Nodejs server. The server is in the net of our university, and it works fine when I access it from inside the university net. However, I get a "net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED" error when I try to connect from outside, and I made sure that the corresponding port is open.
Here is the code:

```
var ws_PORT = xxx;
var fs = require('fs');

var https = require('https');
var cert = fs.readFileSync('path/cert.pem', 'utf8');
var key = fs.readFileSync('path/privkey.pem', 'utf8');
var options = {key: key, cert: cert};
var server = https.createServer(options);
server.listen(ws_PORT);

var WebSocket = require('ws');
var wss = new WebSocket.Server({server: server});

wss.on('connection', function(ws) {
console.log('WS_SERV: Connected to port: '+ws_PORT);
    // Manage ws
    // ...
}
```

Any ideas...?

Thank you in advance,

Answer (score 2):

If you are inside of a university network then the connection is going to be blocked by the university firewall. You would need to create some kind of port forwarding rule on the firewall but if you aren't an administrator than they aren't going to let you do that and if you are an administrator and already tried that and it is not working then double check the firewall rule and both the public and internal IP.

Or, if you are looking to make this publicly accessible, the easiest would just be to throw it on a VPS behind nginx on Digital Ocean, AWS, or linode